# What's difference between these 2 statements?

Tags: sql-server

Which is correct? or both? Why?

1st:

```
INSERT INTO table (num)
VALUES (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM table);
```

2nd:

```
INSERT INTO table (num)
VALUES (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table + 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither one of these statements is correct in their current form.

If you want to insert values from the output of a `SELECT` statement, you need to remove the `VALUES` keyword.

Once that's done, we are left with:

```
-- First statement (will execute successfully)
INSERT INTO table (num) (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM table);

-- Second statement (will not parse)
INSERT INTO table (num) (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table + 1);
```

The SQL Server parser will not even parse the second statement. `table + 1` is not recognised as a valid table name or view. You'll get an error like this:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

To force the behaviour you're trying to compare, we have to do this construction (notice the additional `SELECT` and extra brackets):

```
-- Second statement (forced)
INSERT INTO table (num) (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) + 1);
```

Only now are the query plans identical.

[image]

---

The question originally contained an extra set of brackets around the `SELECT` statements, making my above comments about the `VALUES` keyword moot.

With the brackets, the two statements are functionally identical, as pointed out by several other people, and result in the same query plan.

```
-- Code taken from Martin Smith's comment
INSERT INTO  T (num) VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM T));
INSERT INTO  T (num) VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T) + 1);
```

Comment: I would expect the first statement to execute with the `VALUES`, Did you try it?

Comment: The first statement is entirely correct albeit not ideal. As I stated before and you restated here, values is unnecessary.

Comment: @ShooterMcGavin How is the first statement in the question "entirely correct" if it doesn't even parse?

Comment: The statement before the edits contained an extra set of parenthesis.  It actually allowed it to parse fine.  Now despite that it would parse, I wouldn't say it's "entirely" correct because as soon as you use a SELECT in an INSERT, the VALUES keyword becomes useless.  That being said, it was correct in that it would do what was expected.

Answer (score 3):

I was answering the question it its first form, where there were parentheses and the queries were syntactically correct (before the edits that removed parentheses):

> Which is correct? or both? Why?
>
> 1st:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table (num) VALUES 
> ((SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM table));
> ```
>
> 2nd:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table (num) VALUES 
> ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) + 1);
> ```

In this instance, they are identical except for perhaps the execution plan which honestly probably wouldn't be very different anyways.
I prefer the first one in terms of readability.  Generally, unless there is a windowed function or sub-query, there's no reason to have the +1 after the full select/from statement.  There's no really a good reason to nest the statement with all the extra parenthesis.  In fact, I could see how the second option would cause some confusion in terms of readability.

One more point, when you're using a SELECT for the values on an insert statement, you don't actually need the keyword values.  To simplify try this

```
INSERT INTO table (num) 
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the redundant brackets. This will be more clear.

Comment: Without the extra brackets, I don't actually think the second option will work. Hence my preference of the first option.  Readability and modifiability down the road will be easier with the first option.

Comment: No, they are not identical. The second statement does not even parse, even assuming the VALUES keyword is removed.

Comment: The statements were changed. Once the parentheses were removed, the second statement was no longer valid.

Comment: @RandolphWest I've edited the answer to show what exactly it was answering.